# How can I customize specific icons in a VS Code file icon theme- ideally without creating a new theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change a few icons in the default VS Code icon theme (I have the SVGs)

Is it possible to do this? (or would I need to fork the theme and manually place the icons in?)

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? e.g. [File Icon Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme)

Comment: That seems to be to create a new theme. I want to find out if that is the only/best way (I think it'd be preferable to just stick with the default theme while changing just several icons, if possible)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, you have to [create your own file icon theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/file-icon-theme) based on the theme you want to modify. [VS Code's builtin file icons use Seti](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes#_seti-icon-theme), and they can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/theme-seti/icons) (the product icons (which are for [product icon themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/product-icon-theme)) can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-icons/tree/main/icons)).

There's an open issue ticket requesting a feature you'd probably like: [[theming] customize file icons in settings #44026](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44026). You can give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to get notified about discussion and progress. But please [avoid making noisy "+1" or "bump comments"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions).

---

If you're okay with a solution that involves an extension, it depends what extension you're using. Check your icon theme extension's docs to see if it has a mechanism for customizing icon themes. For example,

- https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons/wiki/Custom
- https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme#custom-svg-icons

Answer (score 0):

There's a [feature request on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44026) for this